# some questions regarding the JFrog Artifactory Deployer plug-in in TFS: team foundation server

Tags: deployment, tfs

I have a small amount of JFrog Artifactory experience, much less using the JFrog Artifactory Deployer plug-in in TFS (team foundation server). Before posting here I tried to find answers in the JFrog online documentation and also checked here:

http://forums.jfrog.org/Artifactory-Users-f2377369.html

and learned that the forum moved from there to stackoverflow last year.

I searched in both places for my issues but didn't find anything.

**Background:**

I'm having trouble deploying a zip file (containing my build results) to a JFrog artifactory (hosted within my company).

I am able to deploy from my workstation manually using, essentially, the following:

jfrog.exe rt upload '.\some.zip' 'path/where/i/want/it/' --url=(our-local-artifactory)

(The first time I tried this, jfrog.exe helpfully offered to set up my local settings, including credentials, so I don't need to supply these.)

My goal is to execute an analogous command as the last step of a TFS build (using a JFrogArtifactoryDeployer plug-in step).

**Question 1**

Initially I had hoped to be able to specify one or two parameters computed in the previous (powershell script) step, but this didn't work and the log entry seemed to explain why -- what was executed began:

jfrog.exe' rt upload '$env:FullArchivePath' ...

so my naive hope that the reference to the persistent variable I had set would be replaced with its value wasn't born out by how the plug-in appears to work. Question one is therefore: is there some way to do this?

**Question 2**

I then began trying a simpler approach using a hard-coded destination path (Target Repository) and a source path (Path to the Artifacts) which was hard-coded except for *.zip at the end (and then I checked the box saying "Is a regular expression used in 'Path to the Artifacts'?")

(Interestingly it *is* possible to use Build Definition Variables in these fields -- their values are substituted as expected.)

However I can't seem to get past an error at this point:

C:\TFS-Agent\_work\30\s\some\other\directories\*.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Wondering whether the doubled back-slashes are harmful I've also tried hard-coding this path with single back-slashes. That doesn't seem to matter, although with (apparently) the same source path I sometimes get

```
Path does not exist: C:\TFS-Agent\...
```

and sometimes:

```
GetFileAttributesEx  C:\TFS-Agent\...\*.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

So question 2 is essentially: why is this syntax incorrect?

I'd be grateful for help with either question or both.

Comment: Could you share your jfrog task settings as a screenshot?

Comment: hi, Patrick, thanks,

Do you mean the JFrog deployer plug-in dialog / form or some user settings associated with whatever user runs these builds under TFS? (Analogous to the ones I have locally in ~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf).

Comment: Hi @Tim According to your description ` the last step of a TFS build (using a JFrogArtifactoryDeployer plug-in step` It seems  it works well in local, just not work with tfs build definition. So not sure if you are setting well in the related task. And what's the detail error info did you get in the build log?

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I think all my settings are "correct", but '*.zip' does not appear to be supported, as I explain in my post. I wonder what the checkbox labelled "Is a regular expression used in 'Path to the Artifacts'?" means. Maybe you know a link to documentation that explains precisely what format of regular expressions is supported?